# Как переназначить из консоли клавиши в KDE?

Tags: linux, консоль, kde, manjaro

В Manjaro KDE Edition 64x 17.0.1 можно через меню назначить клавиши, например:

System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts -> KWin
Параметры системы -> Комбинации клавиш -> Глобальные комбинации клавиш -> KWin

Распахнуть окно на левую половину экрана: Meta+Ctrl+Left
Распахнуть окно на правую половину экрана: Meta+Ctrl+Right
Распахнуть окно: Meta+Ctrl+Up
Распахнуть окно на нижнюю половину экрана: Meta+Ctrl+Down

Как мне это сделать командами через консоль? Эти типовые настройки я всегда делаю, хочу автоматизировать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59822/discussion-on-question-by-pedrosangre-------kde).